# Perl - Conditional printing to console or file

Tags: perl, redirect, output

Am a perl newbie and I want some help with conditional redirection to console or output file. Could someone tell me what's the best way to do this?

1) The number of sentences that I have to print are numerous, so I don't want to multiple if statements for each sentence that I want to print
2) I want to have the option of printing to console for quick viewing or redirect it to output files (the number of output files that could be created could any number)
3) If i create a subroutine as listed, the number of times that I open a particular file could become very high
4) The text/sentence that i want to print to console or file is complex (could be other perl/C code that i am printing)

```
sub print_2_file_or_console {
    my ($print_to_file, $filename, $text) = @_;
    if($print_to_file==1) {
    #open file and redirect text to file

    #close file
    }
    else {
    print "$text\n";
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Standard output is just a handle like opened file is.

```
    my $fh;
    open($fh, ">". $file_name) or die $!;
    my $outh = $print_to_file ? $fh : *STDOUT;
    print $outh $some_string;
    close($fh);
```

Note that this code will always create a file.